# Convert list of FQDN and IPs to two column CSV

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I'd like to take a list like this:

```
example.com
1.2.3.4
ftp.example.com
2.3.4.5
3.4.5.6
www.example.com
4.5.6.7
5.6.7.8
6.7.8.9
```

And parse into a comma delimited CSV format so that when opened in a popular spreadsheet program, the parent FQDNs are in column A and the children IPs are in column B.

I'd like to do this using native Linux binaries so I can bake into an existing BASH script.

Any help welcome, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why my question has been down-voted. At least leave a comment to say why.

Comment: Thanks to both **potong** and **skmrx**. Both great answers. I chose sed in the end as it was a little neater appending to an existing sed argument.

Comment: Neither sed nor a shell loop are the right approach, awk is. Using sed for anything other than simple substitutions on individual lines is fine as a mental exercise but don't really use that in code you might have to look at again some day and try to enhance. Shell loops should be avoided for text processing, e.g. see http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/[[:alpha:]]/h;//d;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2,\1/' file
```

If the line contains alphabetic characters i.e. is an address, store it in the hold space and then delete it. Otherwise, append the address to the current line and then swap the two fields replacing the newline by a `,` and print.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I read the question incorrectly. My solutions below print the hostname and then a list of IP addresses rather than a list of hostname + ip address pairs.

I would use the following logic: For each line of input,

1. If the text has something other than an IP address, print a new line character and then print the text. The new line character is not printed for the first line of text.
2. Otherwise, print a comma and then the text

Examples:

Perl:

```
perl -npe 'chomp;  $_ = /[^\d.]/ ? "$p$_" : ",$_"; $p="\n"'
```

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ [^0-9.] ]]; then
        echo -en "$pre$line"
    else
        echo -n ",$line"
    fi
    pre="\n"
done
```

Comment: I cant comment on the perl script because it might be the chemical formula for penicillin for all I know, but never use a shell loop to manipulate text. The guys who invented shell for manipulating files and processes and sequencing calls to tools also invented awk for shell to call to manipulate text. A shell loop will always be less robust, less portable, and far less efficient than an equivalent awk script. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for one discussion on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. If you are using sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you are using constructs that became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

```
$ awk '/^[[:alpha:]]/{f=$0;next} {print f","$0}' file
example.com,1.2.3.4
ftp.example.com,2.3.4.5
ftp.example.com,3.4.5.6
www.example.com,4.5.6.7
www.example.com,5.6.7.8
www.example.com,6.7.8.9
```

Note how clear and simple this is just because awk has variables, which sed does not. It's also, coincidentally, slightly briefer than a sed approach if you care about that, and I would bet executes faster if your file is large. It will also portably work on all POSIX (due to the POSIX character class) awks on all OSs, it is not GNU-specific.

To address the comment below, IF you wanted all the IP addrs on one line per FQDN then this is one way to do it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^[[:alpha:]]/ { recs[++numFqdns] = $0; next }
{ recs[numFqdns] = recs[numFqdns] "," $0 }
END {
    for (fqdnNr=1; fqdnNr<=numFqdns; fqdnNr++) {
        print recs[fqdnNr]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
example.com,1.2.3.4
ftp.example.com,2.3.4.5,3.4.5.6
www.example.com,4.5.6.7,5.6.7.8,6.7.8.9
```

Alterantively, the direct awk translation of this shell script from skmrx's answer:

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ [^0-9.] ]]; then
        echo -en "$pre$line"
    else
        echo -n ",$line"
    fi
    pre="\n"
done
```

would be:

```
awk '{
    if (/[^0-9.]/) {
        printf "%s%s", pre, $0
    }
    else {
        printf ",%s", $0
    }
    pre="\n"
}'
```

but you'd never really write that in awk, instead the idiomatic way of writing that type of logic in awk would be:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s", (/[^0-9.]/ ? pre : ""), $0; pre=RS }'
```

and you can add `END{print ""}` to print the final newline that was missing from the shell script.

Comment: The question was slightly different though. The requestor wants all the IPs below a host name to appear on the same line, separated by commas. Would it be possible for you to update your answer? It'll be nice to see how it's done in awk!

Comment: I disagree, this is exactly what was requested. The OP said he wants to open the result in Excel or similar and see the FQDNs in one column and the IP addrs in the other. If we listed all the IP addrs associated with an FQDN as comma-separated on one line then the Excel would have the FQDNs in 1 column but then various numbers of other columns - it's be practically useless. What I output above is also the output the OP is getting from the sed script he accepted as the right answer. Having said that, sure I'll post an awk script that formats it the other way. Just give me a min...

Comment: @skmrx OK, I posted a script to do that.

Comment: You're right - your solution was what was requested; sorry about that. Looks like I read the question wrong. But thanks for taking the time to write the additional script!

Comment: @skmrx I added another awk way of doing it so you can see more clearly the relationship between your shell script and the awk script.